# What is the expected avg squared deviation from a randomly chosen number?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I am interested in the following. Given some observed data, if I chose a randomly chosen data point, what would be the average squared deviation from this data point?

I know I could compute this computationally. But is there any way to manipulate things like the mean and SD to get this.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^*$ is your data point, the mean squared distance should be $(\operatorname{mean} - x^*)^2 + \operatorname{var}$, coming from $\int _{-\infty} ^\infty (x - x^*)^2  \operatorname{pdf} (x) \ \mathrm dx$.